# Кто формирует язык в публичной сфере

Tags: общие-вопросы

Правильно ли, что русский язык в публичной сфере формируют не писатели и поэты, не профессионалы-лингвисты, не народ, а рекламщики, коммерсанты, полуграмотные радио- и телеведущие? Лингвисты-русисты довольствуются только тем, что записывают за последними, "фиксируют в словарях" весь этот бред - неблагозвучие, искажение/подмена смыслов, коверкание иностранных слов, нарушение русской грамматики и т.п. Из всех цивилизованных стран, к коим я отношу и восточные цивилизации, это допускается только в России. Сейчас язык формируют не поэты и писатели, как в 18-м, 19-м и 20-м веках в России, не народ (фольклор, Шукшин, писатели-деревенщики и т.д.), не профессора и доктора филологии, как во Франции, Исландии, Израиле, Канаде, арабских странах, Китае, странах Юго-Восточной Азии, а те, кто имеет единоличный доступ к СМИ - рекламщики и журналисты. Кстати, многие из них сидят на американской кормушке - понятно почему им дорог и приятен плебейский американский суржик. А русский народ сейчас как раз не имеет возможности быть услышанным. Он не только не придумывает американизмы и не слизывает их с американских изданий и каналов, но он даже не понимает их значения и не хочет ими пользоваться.

Comment: Гусляр!

Вы куда-то пропали!
А ведь были правы - клюют!
Да еще как!

Мной создано достаточно тем для серьезного обсуждения, однако "наши партнеры" продолжают бездумно ставить минусы. 

Хорошие комментарии - большая редкость.
Не пропадайте!

Comment: Дорогой Федя, "наши партнеры" меня вырубили в бан, чтобы им никто не мешал тут царствовать с их антирусскими и антинаучными установками. Они работают сыгранно: ставят друг другу плюсы за всякие глупости, а при больших баллах они могут удалять наши с Вами сообщения, что они и делают. В общем, действуют по отработанной у них за тысячи лет методе - поддержать не правого, а своего. :)

Comment: Уважаемый Федя, пора и нам у них учиться и перенимать положительный опыт. Надо перестать быть атомизированными. А то так они ещё сто лет над нами будут господставовать. Им мало финансов, СМИ, юриспруденции, искусства, они уже нам указывают, какой должен быть НАШ язык. Представляете, если бы Вы также диктовали свои правила идишу или ивриту? Туда они никого не пускают.

Comment: Да и в арабский арабы никого не пускают. Только русский язык "открыт для всех". :)

Comment: Федя, я бы рад оценить Ваши темы, но у меня украли баллы. :) Опять начинать с нуля...

Comment: Действительно, Гусляр, вижу у Вас всего 1 балл!
Как это удалось сделать?
Заметил еще, что и некоторые комментарии в моих темах пропадают.
Вероятно, кто-то всеми этими процессами управляет.


По поводу банов я не переживаю. Не мы хозяева. Тот, кто этим злоупотребляет, вредят себе же. Наше с Вами участие далеко не праздное. Вы - за чистоту и исконность русского языка, я - за историческую справедливость. Отгораживаясь от нас, "партнеры" вредят настоящему и будущему языка, а значит и благополучию нашего отечества.

Гусляр! У меня в профиле есть почтовый адрес. Можем сообщаться по личной почте.

Comment: Вчера вынес на обсуждение ВОПРОС: Близкие ли слова? (http://goo.gl/wku92k), где привел сравнение между союзом ИЛИ, старо-русским АЛИ, греческим αλλα (однако, но)...
И что Вы думаете? Не успел получить еще ни одного ответа, но кто-то уже умудрился поставить мне два МИНУСА! 
Или действительно на форуме не понимают всю серьезность моих тем, которыми занимаюсь давно и тщательно, или наоборот, очень хорошо понимают.

Comment: Заметил еще, что насколько хорошо комментируются и "отвечаются" вопросы по современному состояния языка, настолько же беспомощно выглядят ответы и комментарии относительно истории языка, этимологии, сравнительному анализу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вернёмся  к  слову  "спонсор".  Вот  как  объясняет  его  Википедия: "спонсор — индивидуум или группа, которая обеспечивает поддержку, подобную благотворителю. Однако, в отличие от благотворительности, спонсирование не носит бескорыстного характера. Спонсирование может быть договорным, обмениваться на рекламирование с целью популяризации товара или юридического лица".  Конкретное  значение,  русского  полного  синонима  нет.  Нет  ни  ругательного,  ни  оскорбительного  оттенка.  Может  иметь  место  неправильное  употребление  этого  слова,  например:  как  можно  быть  спонсором  своего  ребёнка.  Здесь  гарантии  нужно  давать  другими  словами.

Answer (score 3):

Язык
 формирует народ, а лингвисты его фиксируют. Все излишки как только мода
 пройдет исчезнут. Слова "герла" и "шузы" были популярны в 70-х, а 
сейчас о нех почти никто не помнит. "Вау" в 90-е слышалось с каждого 
столба, а сейчас почти исчезло из медиапространства. Те слова, что 
все-таки приживаются, под влиянием русских слов, зачастую меняют свое 
значение. Так не любимый вами "котедж" вытесняет не русский "дачный 
домик", а французскую "виллу". "Креативность" прекрасно дополнила 
русское "творчество", разделив искусство ради искусства и прикладное 
проявление абстрактного мышления.

Да, мне тоже доводилось с офисными москвичками беседующих на 
русско-английском суржике, но в массы такой язык не пойдет, просто 
потому, что массам он не понятен.

Не волнуйтесь, язык впитавший в себя угро-финские, тюркские языки, 
переживший нашествие греческих, польских, церковно-славянских, немецких и
 французских слов, английскими словами тоже не подавится.

---

Русские неологизмы двух последних десятилетий:

> беспредел, рукопожатный, игроман, играбельность, эфэсбэшник, мышка, мобильник, секретутка, паркетник, шубохранилище,  бродилка, обзорщик, козяблики, православнутый и др.

Список далеко не полный и сюда не входят русские слова из не русских корней ("вау-фактор", "аристономия"), слова приобретшие новое значение (ватник, пиндос) и приобретшие в русском языке новое значение (памперс, джип, котедж), а также те, что не вспомнил или не знаю.

Comment: @Марк Из Как раз уже давится.В эпоху всех перечисленных Вами заимствований не было информационного диктата СМИ и рекламы.Сейчас этот мусор моментально фиксируется исполнительными и угодливыми русистами-чинушами и становится "русским".Сколько Вы назовете русских неологизмов,вошедших в обиход за последние 20 лет?Я только 2-"беспредел" и "косяк".А американизмов-под тысячу.В том-то и проблема, что сейчас НЕ НАРОД формирует язык, а МОНОПОЛИЯ СМИ и рекламы.Откуда у народа доступ к публичному полю?Спросите у народа,нужны ему Ваша "кривативность","сЭкс-главы", "жопинги", "трынды", "брендни"?Спросите!

Comment: @Марк Из Более того, этот собачий язык стремительно влезает в официальную переписку. (Если Вы когда-нибудь её читали.) Сейчас при получении визы от меня требуют в ИНОСТРАННОМ консульстве, чтобы я письменно подтвердил, что я являюсь для своего ребенка "спонсором"?! Вообще-то это ругательное слово. Так, они скоро будут от Вас требовать письменного подтверждения, что Вы "пидор" (извините, это только для примера и яркости). ПОЧЕМУ У НАС В СТРАНЕ не профессионалы, как во Франции, у арабов, да везде, а торгаши и иностранцы диктуют нам родной язык???

Comment: @Марк Из Ну вот видите,сколько из них русскими не являются: играбельность-англиский суффикс, незачет; мобильник-нерусский (у французов родное-портабль), секретутка-нерусский; паркетник-сдох,заменен кроссовером; остальные примеры, кроме моего "беспредела"-жаргонизмы и ругательства, Вы бы ещё матерные производные привели,незачет; рукопожатный,мышка,бродилка,шубохранилище, производные от аббревиатур существовали ещё до Вашего рождения; памперс, джип, котедж - это ТО, о чём я и ору в Ваши уши - это американизмы! Плевать на новые значения, у нас богатейшие источники для родного словообразования.

Comment: @Марк Из Дополнение:слова из нерусских корней русскими НЕ являются.Это слова Вашей гламурной фени или американского суржика."Вау-фактор"-это лексикон аудитории Кащенко?Как Вы не поймете,что то,что я проповедаю-это АКСИОМА для всех других приличных культур.И непременно придут времена,когда русский народ начнет ТРЕБОВАТЬ уважения к своей культуре.Вам Манежки мало?Лучше это сделать цивилизованно сейчас,чем дождаться прихода русского яроша.Иначе второй вариант - исчезновения русских как народа. Язык - это ГЛАВНЫЙ народообразующий фактор.Поэтому,если народ планирует сохраниться-будет чистка языка.

Comment: Многие иностранные слова, пришедшие к нам, на деле - всего лишь русские "возвращенцы".

Упомянутые здесь английские "ШУЗЫ" - результат заимствования русск. ШАГ, ШАГАТЬ. Например, в венг. ATHAGNI - перешагивать, преступать. В греч. ΠΡΟΣΕΓΓΙΖΩ (ПРОСЕГГИЗО) - подойти.

В нем. SCHUH - ботинок, обувь.
В англ. SHOE - обувать, обувь и.т.п.

Answer (score 2):

Забавно: как только увижу "полуграмотные СМИ" и прочие сердитые слова, так уверен – аффтар сам полуграмотный. И точно! Аффтар даже не понимает, что профессионалы-лингвисты не создают язык и даже не исправляют его. По простой причине: это невозможно. Это примерно как закон Ома подправить. В ШКОЛУ, АФФТАР!

Comment: Решил перечти на личность? Давай, вызов принят! Буду тебе писать на твоём быдланском языке. Съезди во Францию, в арабские страны, в Китай или почитай что-нибудь про Французскую академию языка, которая ежегодно выпускает справочники французских неологизмов для ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОГО использования в СМИ. Там, что, не лингвисты-профессионалы работают? И это, что, не регулирование языка? Кто, по-твоему, создал огромный лексический пласт всей компьютерной, технической и т.п. французской терминологии. Именно лингвисты и спецы в этих областях. Делается это централизовано, сверху и имеет оязательный характер

Comment: Откуда дровишки?

Comment: @Niemand "Автор даже не понимает" - При чем тут "понимать", я просто ЗНАЮ, что это есть в других странах и отлично работает. У арабов язык формируют филологи в университетах, поэтому в арабском НЕТ ВООБЩЕ американизмов. Твоё невежество - не повод для высокомерия и хамства. Сначала поинтересуйся, что в мире происходит за пределами твоей деревни "рашки", где вы родной язык самозабвенно засераете, как свиньи. Твоя мантра "язык НЕВОЗМОЖНО регулировать" - это пустой звук. Евреи и словаки вообще воссоздали уже умершие языки. Им что не пришлось придумывать неологизмы, которые накопились за это время

Comment: Аффтар, вы неадекватны. Это эвфемизм такой. ))))

Вы уже пытались тут найти русский эквивалент спонсора, и выглядели очень бледно.

А вообще могу дать простой совет. Хотите оградить какой-нить язык от внешних влияний – улетите с ним на Луну.

Comment: @Niemand Не смените тон с быдланского на человечий,я перейду на Ваш же язык.Конечно-не адекватен(не хватает русских слов?),но не адекватен только тебе.По делу:Не пытался,а УЖЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ русское слово,которое используется  двести лет РОВНО в такой же ситуации-это "поручитель".Советы давайте Вашей бабушке.Если не выучил ни одного иностранного языка кроме английского,то пойди со своим "советом" к французам,канадцам,арабам,китайцам,корейцам,индусам,евреям+десятки народов=численность-большая половина населения Земли.Продемонстрируйте ИМ своё НЕВЕЖЕСТВО,что язык нельзя защитить от американизации!

Answer (score 1):

[[@Серж](/users/1826/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6)](/users/1826/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6) Уважаемый Серж, Вы подняли серьезную и интересную тему(Ваше дополнение к собственному сообщению). Я готов попунктно ответить на Ваши замечания. 1.Нам не должно быть никакого дела до того, как иностранное слово закреплено в каких-то словарях, которые пишут такие же грешные люди. "Спонсор дочери или жены" звучит для русского уха периода последних 20 лет ОСКОРБИТЕЛЬНО. Это медицинский факт. И мы не обязаны в НАШЕМ родном языке подстраиваться под иностранцев.2.Между родным и иностранным словом есть принципиальная разница: например, русское слово "кончить" или "трахнуть" я совершенно спокойно могу использовать в нейтральном/первоначальном значении "кончил институт", "трахнул по голове". В приличном обществе это будет воспринято именно в классическом литературном смысле. В противном случае тот, кто засмеётся, продемонстрирует своё незнание русской классической литературы и дурной тон. Но иностранное слово воспринимается именно с той коннотацией, которая присуща данной фразе. Оно изначально вошло в наше поле в таком значении. А как там у иностранцев - это не наше дело. Негоже уважающей себя культуре прогибаться под иностранные языковые реалии и ставить себя, таким образом, в зависимое, вассальное культурное положение. (То, что я сейчас пишу, давно пройдено французами, арабами, китайцами и другими великими культурами, и для них это аксиоматично. Печально, что русским приходится объяснять простейшие вещи, да ещё и преодолевать сопротивление.)3."Поручитель" или "обеспечитель" - это ровно то же слово, которое использовалось во всех точно таких же ситуациях на протяжении более 200 лет. И должно продолжать использоваться!Вы же пользуетесь, извините, перевернутой логикой: они хотят "спонсор", значит надо найти русский синоним "спонсора". Да не нужно искать никаких синонимов! Надо пользоваться русскими языковыми реалиями. Это ЗАКОН перевода. Поговорки и пословицы - НЕ ПЕРЕВОДЯТСЯ, а подбираются аналоги в языке-мишени. Так же и отдельные слова не переводятся тупо, а подбирается слово, которое используется в языке-мишени именно в такой же ситуации. Но оно может не являться точным переводом слова из языка-источника. (Вы, вероятно, не переводчик - можете не знать. Но это закон перевода советской школы.)Поэтому исходить надо из того, что в России в подобных ситуациях выдавались Письма Поручителя. Именно так это называется. А потом уже, если кому интересно, можно посмотреть, как это будет по-английски. У них, возможно, это "заявление спонсора", но это уже их, а не наше дело. (Кстати, тогда, по Вашей логике, и слово "заявление" надо заменить на американское, типа "стейтмент". Вам понравится, если от Вас потребуют, дайте нам "спонсор стейтмент". Тогда надо уже полностью переходить на английский и не издеваться над русским языком.)Ещё раз повторюсь: то, что я сейчас объясняю - это ОЧЕВИДНЕЙШИЕ вещи для многих народов, уже переболевших этой детской болезнью подражательства американцам и заискивания перед ними. Они (эти народы) провели чистки своих языков (японцы, турки, греки, французы), некоторым этого не понадобилось (арабы, китайцы), но все они четко для себя решили, что родной язык не должен развиваться по законам дарвинизма, а его НЕОБХОДИМО защищать, если мы хотим его сохранить. Были введены запретительные меры (Франция, Исландия, Квебек, арабские страны, Китай и т.д.) и заработали свои профессионалы: Французская академия языка, арабские университеты занимаются СЛОВООБРАЗОВАНИЕМ, то есть искусственным созданием слов на основе родных корней. Благодаря этому ни в арабском, ни во Французском нет американизмов ДАЖЕ в таких сферах, как IT, компьютеры, техника и т.д., не говоря о таком варварстве, как тупое замещение и вытеснение в архаику самых обычных бытовых слов (то, что происходит у нас сейчас: "анонсировать", "консолидировать", "презентовать", "шоу" и т.д.).4.У меня более, чем достаточно образований, чтобы знать про заимствования в русском языке (давайте без жлобства!). Речь идет ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО о НЕОПРАВДАННЫХ заимствованиях, ЗАМЕЩАЮЩИХ русские слова и корни. Никто на Ваши "амбары" и "сабли" не покушается! Речь идет ТОЛЬКО об американизмах последних 20 лет. И элементах английской грамматики, которые нам тоже впихивают: "-инг-овое" окончание; суффиксы: "-абель-ный", "-ант" ("подписант"); английские определения: "онлайн магазин", "Киркоров шоу" - по-русски: "онлайновЫЙ магазин", "шоу КиркоровА" и т.д. В глазах тех же американцев мы выглядим, как мартышки. (см.: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=srrTPMjRRsU ) Удивительно, что это позорище, сами русские не видят! 5.Кто Вам сказал, что русский язык ЕДИНСТВЕННЫЙ, который является великим и могучим? Вы много знаете иностранных языков? Я, например, считаю арабский язык гораздо более великим и могучим. В арабском языке ВООБЩЕ нет американизмов. Там ВСЕ слова, включая компьютерные, технические и т.д., все современные - это родные арабские. Арабские лингвисты каждый месяц придувывают из арабских корней НЕОЛОГИЗМЫ вместо американских, как это у нас. Вы же сами постоянно расписываетесь в своём бессилии и скудоумии - "нет русского синонима", а у арабов есть синонимы! Это всё благодаря арабам-лингвистам, журналистам, публицистам, писателям.6. Отказаться от американизмов - БЕЗ ПРОБЛЕМ. Это уже доказали французы, арабы и т.д. и т.д., механизм давно отработан. Надо просто не сидеть на русской печи в том дерьме, в которое нас опустили рекламщики, барыги и торгаши, а поинтересоваться мировым опытом по защите национальных языков. И тогда Вы увидите насколько НИЧТОЖНЫ и СМЕХОТВОРНЫ все "аргументы" (хотя почти всегда - это пустые огрызания), которые мне бросают высокомерные невежды на этом форуме.

Answer (score 0):

Гусляр, я вас правильно понял: под ругательством  вы имеете в виду слово "спонсор"?

В самом деле, синонимы весьма неприличные.Однако это не значит, что само слово ругательное. Негативный оттенок оно имеет только на сленге. Единственный словарь(не считая словарей синонимов), где я нашел толкование этого слова, это словарь русского арго. Хотя, вряд ли негативное значение слова настолько проникло в общество, что и само слово начало восприниматься как ругательное. Ср.например, слово "кончить". Всем , думаю,известно его второе значение. Или ,например, слово "тра***ть"(извиняюсь жаргон), еще в 1980-ых, это слово не имело не имело никакой негативного значения. Затем, под влиянием, уличного жаргона, это слово приобрело другое, негативное значение. Далее произошла семантическая трансформация.Второе значение полностью стерло второе. Да и со словом "кончить" дела обстоят не очень. Хотя второе негативное значение еще не стерло его первое значение, тем не менее, второе, негативное значение уже прочно закрепилось за этим словом. что нельзя сказать о слове "спонсор". Следовательно, и о ругательстве не может идти речи.

Уважаемый Гусляр! Слово это закрепилось лишь в словаре арго и широкого распространения не получило. В официальных словарях это слово в этом значение еще не закреплено. Во-вторых, какая разница какое слово - наше или иностранное получило негативную коннотацию. Значит наше слово с негативной коннотацией вас не беспокоит, а иностранное оскорбляет. Слово ПОРУЧИТЕЛЬ,-( Офиц.
Лицо, поручившееся за кого-л., взявшее на поруки кого-л.) , как видите, имеет другое значение. другие синонимы тоже не подойдут. И еще: у "оскорбительного" синонима "спонсор" есть , помимо слова "спонсор'' и другие синонимы.Напр.: мальчик, палка, наследство. Что же, и они для вас оскорбительны? К тому же, очень много слов, о которых , быть может, вы и не подозреваете, в русском языке заимствованы. Оскудел ли наш язык? Отнюдь!  Означает ли это, что надо от них всех отказаться?! Оскудел ли наш язык? Отнюдь! Русский язык единственный , который по праву считается великим и могучим! К тому же, ни я, ни вы, даже если это слово нам не нравится, от него не сможем отказаться.

Вы совершенно правы, Bernard. Это слово не имеет никакого негативного оттенка. Просто в каком-то  словаре арго это слово имеет непристойное значение. Вот и автор вопроса решил, что слово это оскорбительное.

Comment: @Серж Наберите слово "спонсор" в поисковике и посмотрите, какие там даются синонимы. :-)

Comment: @Серж Речь не только не может не идти, она УЖЕ ИДЕТ. Во-первых, Ваши примеры относятся к русским словам, что уже не корректно, т.к. МЫ хозяева этих слов и нам решать, как их употреблять. Во-вторых, "вряд ли" - это не аргумент! Если "спонсор", а Вы сами видели, уже имеет в СЛОВАРЯХ ругательное значение, а в речи и в МОЁМ ЛИЧНОМ понимании - тоже, то я имею ПОЛНОЕ ПРАВО отказаться использовать это слова по отношению к себе, тем более письменно. Так же, как и Вы имеете право запретить употреблять в Ваш адрес слово "петух" - простое и безобидное русское слово. у нас есть русское слово-"поручитель"

Comment: Это всё замечательно, а каким словом вы слово "спонсор" подмените?

Comment: Пишу же - "поручитель". Есть такое старинное доброе русское слово, откройте россиянско-русский словарь, там найдете.

Comment: А почему именно это слово? По значению не подходит, звучит, в принципе, не лучше других. По-моему, если брать случайные слова, то лучше "лось" или "перец"/"оперец". Короче и звучит более гордо. Последнее имеет смысл и этимологически.

Comment: Shady_arc Вот видите, дорогой. У Вас уже перевернулось сознание. Не только у Вас но и у огромного количества нынешней популяции российского народа. Вы, очевидно, не знакомы с теорией перевода, далеки от лингвистики и т.д. Попробую объяснить: "по значению не подходит" - это Вам "2" на экзамене. Мы не должны подгонять слова под ИХ значения. Это они должны писать слова, которые ПРИНЯТЫ в русском языке. А почти во всех случаях в русском языке в ТАКИХ ЖЕ ситуациях требовалось "Письмо ПОРУЧИТЕЛЯ". Почитайте русскую литературу, или банковские и консульские документы советского периода. Развивайтесь.

Comment: @Гусляр, слово "спонсор" также как "йогурт" было заимствовано дважды, но, в отличии от второго с разными значениями, хоть и с одинаковым ударением. Слово спонсор не отняло у "поручителя" ни одного значения, если не верите откройте любой словарь русского языка. Поручитель в отличии от спонсора, отвечает за того, за кого он поручился, а спонсор лишь выделяет деньги, с целью улучшить свою репутацию в глазах общества.

"Спонсор" вытесняет слово "меценат" (тоже не русского происхождения), что не удивительно, в плане произнесения и словообразования "спонсор" удобнее.